# Xamarin Forms detect mouse/finger down event

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to catch the event for when the user presses down there finger/mouse on a label. Right now I am using a `TapGestureRecognizaer` and it works as expected for a full tap/click.

Is there a simple way to get some sort of "MouseDown" event? I've been searching but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to do this is to use a third party package called [Mr.Gestures](http://www.mrgestures.com/#Documentation). Eventhough this plugin does cost $10/app. it gives you the `Mouse Down` event (along with a load of others) on all 3 platforms.

> **Event    |    Description**
>
> Down     |  One or more fingers came down onto the touch screen.